# sqlite mode column and header on, in ruby script

Tags: ruby, sqlite, sqlite3-ruby

You know certainly about .mode column & headers on, to show datas of a sqlite database. But how to obtain the same result wth in Ruby script?

For example, to add it to my own script:

```
begin
    require 'sqlite3'
    db = SQLite3::Database.open('test_albums.db')
    db.execute("select * from albums where ecoute = 2") do |result|
        puts result.join(' - ')
    end
end
```

Very thanks!

Comment: of course, to replace line #5 (puts . . .)

Comment: I'd recommend looking into using [Sequel](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net). It'll make your life easier by allowing you to start with SQLite, then easily switch to a more powerful DBM when you are ready. Also, read "[ask]" and "[mcve]" and "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)"

Comment: Hi,  thanks for advices - I'll see that about Sequel...

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the table info using `pragma table_info()`, e.g.:

```
begin
  require 'sqlite3'
  db = SQLite3::Database.open('test_albums.db')

  columns = db.execute("pragma table_info(albums)")
  puts (columns.map { |c| c[1] }).join(' - ')

  db.execute("select * from albums  where ecoute = 2") do |result|
    puts result.join(' - ')
  end
end
```